# SQL IN statement to extract for 100k records

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a file SRQ which is having 10000 SRQ_ID which are unique.
I have one table(TABLE1) which is having 2 columns namely `SRQ_ID,WORK_ID` .
I needs to write a query which will search the table(TABLE1) for all the SRQ_ID's in the file SRQ and will display the output with corresponding WORK_ID.

I tried the below code. But IN clause is only applicable for 1000 records. How to run the same if I have 100k records?

```
select WO_ID 
from TABLE1 
where SRQ_ID in ('B6512DF0','5838FABC','EC5D804C','074DD65C')
```

Comment: What SQL database are you using?

Comment: @StingyJack seems like it's PostgreSQL

Comment: @deadlock - Is the 1K limit a postgres thing?

Comment: @deadlock: I don't see any indication that this is for Postgres. And judging by the "*applicable for 1000 records*" I actually think it's Oracle, because Oracle only allows for 1000 literal values in the `IN` operator

Comment: Without RDBMS it is unclear what you'Re asking. With RDBMS it is duplicate. Just use a search engine to find out answer and delete this question. This is duplicated 100s of times.

Comment: @StingyJack it's originally an Oracle issue. I thought it's a PostgreSQL too. But it seems not!

Comment: i got the answer using union all approach.. it worked fine for me..thanks a lot to all ..

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you can't just do a join between the tables using SRQ_ID?

```
select wo_id from table1 join srq using srq_id
```

This will give you the work id for all rows that have a srq_id value in the srq table.

Comment: We supposed to check on prod envirionment that is why i was not willing to take that option...

Answer (score 0):

If the file s on the database server then you could access it as an external table, and join the two. Otherwise, I'd suggest bulk loading the codes into a global temporary table and performing the join against that.

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't like to create a temporary table, you can use a nested table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE VARCHAR_TABLE_TYPE AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(20);

select WO_ID 
from TABLE1 
where SRQ_ID MEMBER OF VARCHAR_TABLE_TYPE('B6512DF0','5838FABC','EC5D804C','074DD65C');
```

But I don't know the limit for initializing a nested table. Oracle documentation says: "Because a nested table does not have a declared size, you can put **as many elements** in the constructor **as necessary**."